# How can I get a high resolution time stamp as a double?

Tags: c++, timestamp, c++-chrono

I am trying to use the follow code:

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

to get a time stamp, but I need it as a double, but it isn't a support data type, auto works, but I cannot manipulate it.

Comment: Why do you need it as a double?  What are your time units?

Comment: Generally, using an integral unit such as milliseconds, may be more accurate than using a double precision number.

Answer (score 3):

Your "time stamp" is what the `<chrono>` library calls a `time_point`.  A `time_point` is a collection of a clock, and duration.  And a duration is a collection of a representation and period.

You have specified two out of these three:

- `clock == high_resolution_clock`
- `representation == double`
- `period ==` ?

Your period can be `nano` (`ratio<1, 1000000000>`), `milli` (`ratio<1, 1000>`), `seconds` (`ratio<1>`), `minutes` (`ratio<60>`) or any other rational relationship to seconds.

Let's say for example that you wanted a time stamp using double as the representation and seconds as the period.  This would look like this:

```
using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using dsec = std::chrono::duration<double>;
using tps = std::chrono::time_point<clock, dsec>;
tps tp = clock::now();
```

The `time_point` emitted by `high_resolution_clock::now()` will implicitly convert to your `time_point` using a representation of double and a period of ratio<1>.  It will hold fractional seconds since the epoch of `high_resolution_clock`.

In general, because your destination type has a floating point representation, all time_point source types will implicitly convert to it.  To convert in the reverse direction, you would need to use `std::chrono::time_point_cast<some-duration>(source-time_point)`.

If instead you wanted to hold double-based nanoseconds, that would look like:

```
using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using dns = std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano>;
using tpns = std::chrono::time_point<clock, dns>;
tpns tp = clock::now();
```

As a guideline, I recommend using either `system_clock` or `steady_clock`, but not `high_resolution_clock`.  Use `system_clock` if your `time_point` needs to have some relationship with the civil calendar, or needs to maintain meaning across processes.  Use `steady_clock` if your `time_point` is used only across short durations within the same process.

`high_resolution_clock` is (de-facto) always an alias to either `system_clock` or `steady_clock`.  So you might as well use one of the latter, and know what you're getting.

```
using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
using dsec = std::chrono::duration<double>;
using tps = std::chrono::time_point<clock, dsec>;
tps tp = clock::now();
```

Comment: great answer with good insight into c++ clock classes! can i append the line to first example in your answer to get actual double utc timestamp: `double ts = tp.time_to_epoch().count(); `?

Comment: I'd rather you didn't.  Rationale:  `.count()` (and for that matter `.time_to_epoch()`) are generally overused by programmers new to this library.  Beginners will call `now()` and *immediately* cast their way out of the type safety of the chrono library.  And I've been on a decade-long campaign to discourage this.  I would rather answer a direct question about how to get the `double` out, so I can learn why it is needed.  Chances are high that once the "why" is known, `.count()` is the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` returns an `std::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>`. Here, you can choose whether you want to express this time point in nanoseconds, microseconds, milliseconds, and so on, using a `std::chrono::duration`, and ultimately convert this to a `double`:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> tp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double, std::micro> dur = tp;
double micros = dur.count();
```

Here you can replace `std::micro` with whatever resolution you desire.